# Problem with 'save_post' hook not running

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, save-post, post-meta

I have a custom post type, with a custom meta box which contains a number of input fields.

The meta box is displaying fine but when completing all the fields the data is not saving, in fact, the function I call with the `save_post` hook does not appear to be running at all...

I use the `register_meta_box_cb` to define my function which adds the meta box for me. I then use the following in my attempt to save the custom data...

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_function', 10, 2 );
function my_save_function( $post_id, $post )    {
    foreach( $_POST as $meta_key => $new_meta_value )   {
        if( substr( $meta_key, 0, 6 ) == 'venue_' ) { // This is verified and correct
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );
        }
    }
}
```

Been staring at this and searching the codex and Google for a couple of hours now with no progress... Whatever I put in that save function just does not execute. I have tried `die()` and error_log at the very top of the function to ensure my checks are not the problem... but nothing. (the function above is a cut down version to what I really have)

Comment: What is your custom post type called? Can we see details? Where is this code placed?

Comment: @PieterGoosen `save_post` is an action hook used in **ALL** post types, including standard posts, pages and custom post types. Also, the post-type specific hook is `save_post_{post_type}`, not `save_{post_type}`.

Comment: The code can be found at https://gist.github.com/mikeyhoward1977/566ce073fbdc7cf167f2/5d4ceee46e4b0001be172591d4de4da8db41c392
the save_post hook is in metabox.php

Comment: I tried `save_{post_type}` but still nothing. I have also tried, `edit_post` and `publish_post`